# Почему не запускается битрикс проект?

Tags: битрикс, windows-7, virtualbox

Скачал [VirtualBox](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.14/VirtualBox-5.1.14-112924-Win.exe), скачал [виртуальную машину](http://repos.1c-bitrix.ru/vm/VMBitrix7.0.0-centos7.2-VirtualBox.zip) битрикс

Установил VirtualBox, открываю виртуальную машину. Выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?
(windows 7 x64 )

Comment: А на скрине что написано?

Comment: Возможно такое исправить програмно?

Comment: Версия ОС выбрана неправильно. Выберите в настройках не RedHat, а RedHat 64 bit.

Comment: В настройках virtualBox нету x64

Comment: Тогда, вероятно, нет аппаратной поддержки виртуализации. Либо железо не держит, либо отключена в BIOS.

Comment: А можна ссилочку где понятно розяснено где и как включить если ето возможно

Comment: Это нужно смотреть в документации к материнской плате. Пункт меню может называться по разному. Но для начала посмотрите на сайте производителя процессора, есть ли в этой модели аппаратная поддержка виртуализации.

Comment: Но на VMware все роботало на старих версиях или там оно както по другому роботало?